# Exporting grouped item as image using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, image, layouts

I have imported an image and added text surrounding this image into a layout through ArcGIS Pro.

I intend on using this as a logo for other maps produced by my team.

How do I export this grouped item as an image file for others to use?

Comment: Have you tried copy/pasting those grouped layout elements into a new layout and then exporting that layout as an image?

Comment: The grouped image/text is not symmetrical and will export with unwanted white space if using this method. Thanks for the idea @PolyGeo !

Comment: Have you looked for ways to make that white space transparent?